# Controlling format/placement of axis labels when plotting 2D table objects in R

Tags: r, formatting, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to gain greater control over axis label size and placement when plotting a 2-dimensional table in R, but the plotting rules seem to work differently for table objects than for data frames. To make my questions concrete, I've pasted in fake data at the end of this message using `dput()`. Running that code will create the `dept.table` object used in the plotting code below.

When you run `plot` on a 2D table in R, it creates a mosaic plot, as in the following:

```
plot(dept.table, 
     col=c("yellow","blue","red"), 
     las=1, 
     cex=.7, 
     dir=c("h","v"), 
     off=c(8,4))
```

There are three changes I'd like to make to the axis labels in the plot created by this call.

First, alternate the height of the "Freshman", "Sophomore", etc. labels across the top, so that they don't overlap (I know I can shorten them, but I want to figure this out for future reference as well, since it's not always convenient to shorten labels). I thought of turning off axis labels and adding them manually with the `text()` function. However, adding `xaxt = 'n'` to the `plot` call evidently doesn't work when plotting a table object (R gives an "extra argument(s) 'xaxt' will be disregarded" message).

Another option is to rotate the x-axis labels by setting `las=2`. However, I'd prefer to have the labels horizontal for easier reading. I should note, though, that when I do set `las=2`, the label "Graduate Student" overlaps onto the plot area.

So there are several issues here:

1. How do I turn off plotting of the x-axis labels so that I can add labels manually?
2. Better yet, is there a more elegant way to get the labels to alternate up and down so that they don't overlap, without having to set the position of each one manually?
3. If a label overlaps the plot area, is there a way (other than shortening the label) to eliminate the overlap?
4. Is there a way to have different text sizes for the x-axis and y-axis labels? The actual plot I want to make has many more departments (the vertical axis) so I'd like to use a smaller text size for the y axis than for the x axis. The only option for axis text size seems to be `cex`, which adjusts both axes. Is there a way to adjust each axis separately?
5. The y-axis labels are left justified. Is there a way to get them right justified, so they'll be close to the plot area?

By the way, although I made this plot with base graphics, I'd be interested in whether there are better ways to do it with lattice, ggplot2, or perhaps another package.

```
dept.table = structure(c(10, 15, 20, 200, 5, 15, 35, 200, 49, 15, 25, 20, 
250, 5, 12, 34, 150, 30, 50, 108, 75, 800, 32, 39, 135, 400, 
195, 80, 99, 64, 700, 47, 41, 134, 350, 160, 5, 10, 5, 110, 5, 
4, 10, 30, 13), .Dim = c(9L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("Anthropology", "Economics", "Mathematics", "Business Administration", 
    "Geography", "Special Education, & Deaf Studies", "History", 
    "Kinesiology & Health Science", "Family & Consumer Sciences"
    ), c("Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior", "Graduate Student"
    )), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

Comment: I've never used it, but you might find something useful in the `vcd` package - "vcd" for "visualizing categorical data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach using ggplot

```
# convert to a data frame
dept_data <- as.data.frame(dept.table)
```

Given you are attempting to plot the proportions (not the raw numbers)

```
# add proportions
library(plyr)
dept_data_prop <- ddply(dept_data, .(Var1), mutate, prop = Freq /sum(Freq))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dept_data_prop, aes(x= Var1, y = prop, colour = Var2, fill = Var2)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~Var1, scales = 'free', ncol = 1) + 
  opts(strip.background =theme_blank(), strip.text.x = theme_blank(), 
       strip.text.y = theme_text(), axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
       axis.title.x = theme_blank(), axis.text.x = theme_blank()) + xlab('') + 
  scale_fill_brewer('Student',  type = 'div', palette = 5) + 
  scale_colour_brewer('Student', type = 'div', palette = 5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

To find out more about the available options, look at `?opts`

The following is adapted from [learning r](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/)

To get the bar widths proportional to the total counts

```
dept_data <- as.data.frame(dept.table)
names(dept_data) <- c('department', 'student', 'count')



dept_prop <- ddply(dept_data, .(department), mutate, 
               prop_department = count / sum(count),
               max_department = cumsum(prop_department),
               min_department = max_department - prop_department,
               total_department = sum(count))


dept_prop <- mutate(dept_prop, prop_total = total_department / sum(count))

dept_prop <- ddply(dept_prop, .(student), mutate, 
   max_total = cumsum(prop_total), 
   min_total = max_total - prop_total)



ggplot(dept_prop, aes(xmin = min_department, xmax = max_department, 
                      ymin = min_total, ymax = max_total)) +
 geom_rect(aes(colour = student, fill =student)) + 
 facet_grid(department~., scales = 'free', space = 'free') +
 opts(strip.background =theme_blank(), 
   strip.text.y = theme_text(hjust = 0.05), axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
   axis.title.x = theme_blank(), axis.text.x = theme_blank(), 
   axis.title.y = theme_blank(), axis.text.y = theme_blank(), 
   legend.position = 'bottom', legend.justification = 'left',
   panel.border = theme_blank(), panel.background = theme_blank(), 
   panel.grid.major = theme_blank(), panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
   xlab('') + 
 scale_fill_brewer('Student',  palette = 'Set1') + 
 scale_colour_brewer('Student', palette = 'Set1') + 
 scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Comment: I like how polished it looks (which is a great advantage of ggplot!). Is there a way to make the bar widths proportional to the number of students in a given department? An advantage of mosaic plots over bar plots is that they add that second dimension of information.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that feature. I've now edited the answer and given a [link](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/) that might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you've put into this. It looks like ggplot maintains a constant vertical space between each horizontal bar. Is there a way to reduce the spaces so it looks more like a "standard" mosaic plot? This could perhaps be the kernel of a "geom_mosaic" addition to ggplot2!

Comment: I've adjusted this again. The problem was using `facet_grid(..., space = 'free'` in conjuction with `coord_flip()`. I've redone the second approach to avoid using `coord_flip()`.